# draw image to CGContextRef and rotate it when do not change the CTM of previous path?

Tags: ios, rotation, cgcontext

I already draw some path on the context.And I want to display a image on it and rotate the image.When I set the CTM the context is all rotating.That's not my purpose.I want to display a image and rotate it,but not change the state of previous path.
What can I do?Any ideas????

Comment: Modifying the transformation matrix should not alter things that you already drew, only subsequent drawings. Anyway, use `CGContextSaveGState()` prior to rotating the matrix, draw your image, then use `CGContextRestoreGState()` to restore the previous matrix.